# How can I create a dynamic webpage using PHP and XML?

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am doing a small website project. In a page their is a section where the client posts new updates, at any given time there will be a maximum of 5 to 6 posts in this division. I was trying to create a MySQL database for the content. But I wonder if their is anyway I could have all the entries as XML files and use PHP to parse it. Is it possible ?

Which one is the better option MySQL or XML?

Comment: XML is used mostly to carry data. Mysql is used to store data. They are not substitute to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is a horrid piece of crap in my opinion.  It's bloated and rather unpleasant to work with.  However, it is a viable option as long as your number of entries and the amount of traffic stays small.

You can use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/simplexml) to parse the XML, but the performance is going to degrade as file size increases.  MySQL, however, will handle quite a lot of data before performance becomes a concern provided the schema is properly setup.

If you do use XML, you could always use a half-way XML solution.  Like parse the file once, then store a serialized array of it.

Though really, if you're going to store it in a file of some sort, I would suggest, in order: SQLite, [serialized array](http://php.net/serialize), [JSON](http://php.net/json_encode), XML.  (Depending on your situation that order may change.)

If you abstract away the low level details enough, you should be able to make adapters that can be used interchangeably, thus allowing you to easily switch out storage backends.  (On a large project, that would likely be unfeasible, but it sounds like your data storage/retrieval will remain fairly simple.)

Comment: Thanks :). My requirement is very simple. A section of the page with a few entries (max 8-10) and each entry contains one header(one line) and a body(max of 5 lines). The client must be able to add new entries  and also remove older entries. Which of the above options would you prefer?

Comment: A serialized array would probably be the easiest to learn.  In the long run though, SQLite or MySQL might be the better option.  If you think the site is likely to grow, or you happen to already have a MySQL server running, I'd use MySQL.  If not, or if you're willing to recode when needed, I'd go with a serialized array.  (Note that a serialized array will limit searching capabilities and whatnot though.)